# Angular: automatically set ordering in list view and show data as it is in $scope object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the data coming from Database into my $scope object:

[In this data coming properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIHY2.jpg)

but when it is render in html it just put first three data at the end of the list:

[Here first three data are at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImUZm.jpg)

Here is my Html code

```
 <select multiple data-ng-model="GlobalTerritories" class="form-control" data-ng-selected="GlobalTerritories">
        <option data-ng-value="key" data-ng-repeat="(key,value) in GlobalTerritoriesList">{{ key +' -- '+ value }}</option>
 </select>
```

I want that data first, so what can i do, please help me.

Comment: You could just reverse the order with what you did `{{ value +' -- '+ key }}`

Comment: it's just for display, how it will affect the order of list?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [**`orderBy`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter to order your options by key:

```
<select multiple data-ng-model="GlobalTerritories" class="form-control" data-ng-selected="GlobalTerritories">
    <option data-ng-value="key" data-ng-repeat="(key,value) in GlobalTerritoriesList | orderBy: key">{{ key +' -- '+ value }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use orderby filter for this.

```
<select multiple data-ng-model="GlobalTerritories" class="form-control" data-    ng-selected="GlobalTerritories">
        <option data-ng-value="key" data-ng-repeat="(key,value) in     GlobalTerritoriesList | orderBy:'key'">{{ key +' -- '+ value }}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: No data, list get blank